# Как найти message.message.message_id?

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот должен удалять своё предыдущее сообщение после ответа пользователя.

Но возникает ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'

Пробовал что-то менять, но выходит ошибка выше или:

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound: Message to delete not found

Что можно сделать?

Код:

```py
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"], state="waitText")
    async def result(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы обращаетесь к объекту Message внутри объекта Message, его там нет :)

Для получения ID сообщения достаточно сделать так: `message.message_id`, вместо `message.message.message_id`